# xmpp for ios,about send message

Tags: ios

/*
how to use xmpp protocol to send message to a specified person in an IOS app,here is my code,but it can't work,i guess my parameters in method are wrong,i don't konw what parameters should be written in method,please help me
*/

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textfd.text];
NSXMLElement *message1 = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message1 addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message1 addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"admin"];
[message1 addChild:body];
_xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
[_xmppStream sendElement:message1];
```

Comment: You need to connect and authenticate your xmpp stream first before you can send any message.

Comment: - (void)sendMessage{
_xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[_xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_current_queue()];
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textfd.text];
NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    NSString *user = @"admin";
    NSString *to = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@tp_web", user];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:to];
    [message addChild:body];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
    
}

Comment: You are in lack of basic knowledge about XMPP. You can download [XMPPframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) from github, and check the example in XMPPFramework/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP. You will get what you want about "XMPP connect and authenticate". After that, you can send your chat message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)sendMessage:(Message *)message
{
    if(message)
    {
        NSXMLElement * msg =  [self composeMessage:message];
        [_xmppStream sendElement:msg];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"message arguments missing");
    }
}

- (NSXMLElement *)composeMessage:(Message *)msg
{
    NSXMLElement *returnValue;
    if(msg.type == IMChat)
    {
        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:msg.text];
        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];// IMChat
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:msg.recipientId];
        [message addChild:body];
        returnValue = message;
    }
    else
    {
        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:msg.text] ;
        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"groupchat"];//Group Chat
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:msg.recipientId];
        [message addChild:body];
        returnValue = message;
    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

Message model contain..

```
typedef enum MessageTypes
{
    IMChat = 1,
    GroupChat = 2
} MessageTypes;

@interface Message : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MessageTypes type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *senderId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *recipientId;

@end
```

Comment: Before u have to initialise xmmppStream and set delegates.FYI:recipientId or senderId, it should be full id like admin@domainName

Comment: let me know the status.

Comment: - (void)sendMessage{
  _xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
  [_xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_current_queue()];
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textfd.text];
NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    NSString *user = @"admin";
    NSString *to = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@tp_web", user];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:to];
    [message addChild:body];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
    
}

Comment: its worked for me.checking ur IDs.Try configure account with iChat or Adium, to make sure Ur IDs are proper